# Table in fastreport databand does not break

Tags: fastreport

In fastreport, my data band goes above the footer band. I want the table in my databand to be split when it doesn't fit on the page.
I tried to set the "Can break" property of both the table, cells and databand to "true" but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was necessary to "can break" both the "databand", the "table cell" and the "table row" at the same time.

Also, don't forget to set the "can grow" property of the databand to true.